# $\bar{.9}$ is distinct from 1 in $\mathbb{R}$ so why does $\bar{.9} = 1$

Tags: calculus

Recently I brought up the idea that $\bar{.9} = 1$ with some friends and asked why or why not. One friend suggested that since $\bar{.9}$ is distinct from 1 in $\mathbb{R}$ they must not be equivalent.

Thoughts?

Comment: Why did your friend believe that $.\overline{9}$ is distinct from $1$ in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: $0.\overline{9}$ is no more distinct from $1$ than $\frac24$ is distinct from $\frac12$: it’s simply a different representation of the same real number.

Comment: What does $0.\overline 9$ really mean ...?

Comment: So given it converges to 1 it is 1.

Comment: @String Apparently that's the way the OP represents $$0.999....=9\sum_{k=0}^\infty10^{-k}$$

Comment: @Timbuc: Yes, thank you. I was just wondering whether the OP made the connection that it really means a limit and not just an infinite string of $9$'s which, as a string, is not identical to $1$.

Comment: You're just asking for controversy aren't you?

Comment: @NonStandard: You just potentially addressed six different people. Who is asking for controversy, and what makes you think that?

Comment: @String I think he was referring to the question's leading nature...

Comment: OK, I find it hard to judge on that, but it could be interpreted that way, I am sure, @Zach466920.

Comment: @String I was mostly projecting.

Answer (score 6):

Try this explanation.  $1/3=0.\overline{3}$ and $2/3=0.\overline{6}$.  Adding the two left hand sides gives one.  Adding the two right hand sides gives $0.\overline{9}$.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will help:
$$
0.\underbrace{999...999}_{n\text{ times}}+\frac1{10^n}=1
$$
Thus
$$
1-0.\underbrace{999...999}_{n\text{ times}}=\frac{1}{10^n}
$$
now what happens as $n$ tends to infinity?

---

As others have noted, $0.\overline 9$ and $1$ are just two different representations of the exact same number.

Comment: You get an infinitesimal, or 0. Pick a side on the debate...

Comment: This is an interesting perspective.

Comment: @Zach466920 The OP picked a side: $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Zach, I can't understand why you think there are sides, and you still bring on infinitesimals after you were said that **also** there both representations are exactly the same number, namely $\;1\;$ . Anywway, this **all** seems to occur in standard, good'ol calculus.

Comment: @Timbuc you're right, I think the whole thing is just semantics. I just think that calculus makes more sense if you don't use limits.

Comment: @Zach466920 Surely you know more on this than I do, since I can't understand (uniform) continuity, derivatives, Riemann integral, etc. without limits.

Comment: @Timbuc I just had a really bad aesthetic experience with the epsilon-delta definitions so I looked for a way that better suited me.

Answer (score 0):

You can always fall back on the old proof of $0.\bar{9} = 1$:

$$x = 0.\bar{9} \\
10x = 9.\bar{9} \\
10x - x = 9.\bar{9} - 0.\bar{9} \\
9x = 9 \\
x = 1 \\
\therefore 0.\bar{9} = 1$$

Like the previous posters explained the two numbers are fundamentally equal, they are the same number.